# Awk change decimal formats

Tags: unix, awk

I've got a file containing decimal values formatted like `9.85E-4`. How can I make awk format this value to `0.000985`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `printf` with the `%f` option:

```
awk '{printf "%f\n", your_field .... }' file
```

#### Example

```
$ cat a
9.85E-4
23
$ awk '{printf "%f\n", $1}' a
0.000985
23.000000
```

From [The GNU Awk User’s Guide # 5.5.2 Format-Control Letters](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Control-Letters):

> **%e, %E**
>
> Print a number in scientific (exponential) notation.
>
> **%f**
>
> Print a number in floating-point notation